# Open Navigation drawer (.openDrawer()) without using Gravity.RIGHT, Gravity.LEFT,

Tags: android

I'm developing multi language app for android. The thing is that I want the drawer to be opened from right if language is RTL and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
android:layout_gravity="end"
```

Add this line to your navigation drawer's listview xml. This will add listview to right side of drawer and it will open from right (or left if in RTL environment).

You can open this drawer by calling

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
```

Comment: And `GravityCompat.END`

Comment: I wants to do this programmatically.

Comment: Then do it like @EugenPechanec said.

Comment: @KhushalChouhan Y u no edit it into your answer so it's complete

Answer (score 1):

Instead of righting left and right you can use the `android:layout_gravity="start"`. This will ensure the direction depending on your language.

Comment: Good Idea, but sadly I'm using api 11.

Comment: in that case you have to programatically change that depending on the language

Comment: @Danial Why is using API 11 a problem?